# Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem, description

How do I create a description list where the item text is automatically indented to the width of the widest label?

This is the same question as [Description list with aligned descriptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67720/6185) but I would like the width of the widest label to be automatically calculated.

For example, I'd like the following output:

[image: example output]

to be produced by the following input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1em,papersize={4in,2.2in}]{geometry}

\newenvironment{mydescription}{%
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=!,
    labelwidth=\magicgoeshere,
    ]%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}

\newcommand{\text}{long long long long long long long long long long
  long long long long long long long long long long long long long
  long long long long long long long text}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
\item[The longest label] text
\item[Short] \text
\end{mydescription}
\hrule
\begin{mydescription}
\item[Medium label] text
\item[Short] \text
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Here is a solution that uses the [`eqparbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package to measure item label widths.
It avoids some of the limitations of the solution described in [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099) (see the bottom of this post) because it doesn't typeset the entire list twice.
The trade-off is that it requires an additional compilation run because widths measured during one run will only become available for the next one.

You can declare a version of the description environment that does what you want by adding the following lines to your preamble.
**(Only works for enumitem v3.7+, see below.)**

```
%% Requires enumitem v3.7+
\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1} %% <- pick a larger number if you want to nest these
\setlist[mydescription]{
    labelwidth=\eqboxwidth{listlabel@\EnumitemId},
    leftmargin=!,
    format=\mydescriptionlabel,
}
\newcommand\mydescriptionlabel[2][l]{\eqmakebox[listlabel@\EnumitemId][#1]{#2}}
```

What this does is put the description item labels in in `\eqmakebox`es so that their widths are written to the aux file.
From the second run onwards, all such boxes in the same list will be given the same width (largest among them) and this width will be used as the list's `labelwidth`.

If you're using a version of `enumitem` that is older than v3.7 (which was released on 2019-01-04), you can still make this work by adding the following lines:

```
%% Only required for enumitem v3.6-
\usepackage{etoolbox} %% <- for \AtBeginEnvironment
\newcounter{mydescription}
\AtBeginEnvironment{mydescription}{%
  \stepcounter{mydescription}%
  \edef\EnumitemId{\arabic{mydescription}}%
}
```

*(N.B. Using the `before` key for this wouldn't work because the code would be run too late.)*

---

### Application to your MWE

Here is my solution applied to your MWE (version for `enumitem` v3.7+).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1em,papersize={4in,2.2in}]{geometry}

\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1} %% <- pick a larger number if you want to nest these
\setlist[mydescription]{
    labelwidth=\eqboxwidth{listlabel@\EnumitemId},
    leftmargin=!,
    format=\mydescriptionlabel,
}
\newcommand\mydescriptionlabel[2][l]{\eqmakebox[listlabel@\EnumitemId][#1]{#2}}

\newcommand{\text}{long long long long long long long long long long
  long long long long long long long long long long long long long
  long long long long long long long text}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
\item[The longest label] text
\item[Short] \text
\end{mydescription}
\hrule
\begin{mydescription}
\item[Medium label] text
\item[Short] \text
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

## How this works

- I used `\newlist` instead of `\newenvironment` to define the `mydescription` environment and `\setlist` to customise it.
  You could of course also forego the `\newlist` and modify the normal `description` environment instead.
- `enumitem`s `format` key is used to put every item label in your `mydescription`  environment in an `\eqmakebox`.
  All `\eqmakebox`es with the same tag will be given the same dimensions (after the second run). They're centred by default, but I provided `[l]` as an option to make them left-aligned.
- The tag used by this `\eqmakebox` includes `\EnumitemId`, which is a unique identifier for the current list environment and is provided by `enumitem`.
- The width of the widest such box for a given list is retrieved using `\eqboxwidth` and used as the `labelwidth` for that list.
- The calculated horizontal length is `leftmargin`, as in your MWE.

The documentation for `enumitem` and `eqparbox` can be found [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) and [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eqparbox/eqparbox.pdf) respectively

#### Notes

- If you want all such list environments in your document to use the same `labelwidth` you can simply remove both instances of `\EnumitemId` in my code snippet.
- These can be nested safely if declared using `\newlist{mydescription}{description}{n}` for with `n` greater than 1.
- To right-align, centre or stretch (multi-word only) your the labels, `\mydescriptionlabel` can be replaced by `\mydescriptionlabel[r]`, `\mydescriptionlabel[c]` or `\mydescriptionlabel[s]` respectively.
- You can combine `\mydescriptionlabel` with other text formatting commands, but they should precede `\mydescriptionlabel` and none of them should take an argument (so `\itshape` is okay, but `\textit` is not).
- The item labels themselves are still typeset twice and assignments made within them will thus still be performed twice, which I feel is unlikely to be a problem.
  This could be avoided, but not without making the preamble significantly longer.
- The labels themselves are still typeset twice, and definitions in the labels will thus still be applied twice as well. This can be avoided but this is less likely to be a problem than typesetting the entire list twice.
- The labels are not allowed to contain anything you wouldn't be allowed to put in a `tabular` environment, but I don't think that's much of a restriction since I can't think anything not allowed in a `tabular` that is allowed in an item label.

---

## Comparison to the other solution

[Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099) will work well in most circumstances, but it's a bit heavy-handed and has a few limitations:

- `\NewEnviron` has a few [subtle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472512/156366) [problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267722/156366) and [restrictions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51239/156366);
- display equations don't work inside lists defined this way;
- counters incremented from anywhere in the list will be incremented twice and the same goes for other global assignments made within the list environment;
- it won't work if the labels don't use boldface formatting;
- multiple such environments can't be nested.

Downsides of my answer:

- My solution requires an additional compilation run because the label widths measured during the first run are only available during the second.

Comment: @RichardHansen: I had overlooked that my answer wouldn't work with versions of `enumitem` older than v3.7. I've added the required code to still make it work and improved the answer while I was at it.

Comment: Terribly underrated answer! I was surprised to find out that this kind of formating doesn't seem to be provided out of the box, eg. by some package. I'd suggest to incorporate this as an option into `enumitem`. For whoever might want to tweak the formating like me: changes of `labelwidth` need to be written somehow like `labelwidth={\dimexpr \eqboxwidth{listlabel@\EnumitemId} + 1em}`

Comment: Thank you :). If you're changing the value of `labelwidth` to change the distance between the label and the item I would recommend using the `labelsep` key instead (or `labelsep*` if you prefer, see the [enumitem documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)). I expect setting `labelsep=\dimexpr\labelsep+1em` (or `labelsep=1.5em` in a 10pt `article` with no further customisation) will have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 29):

A variation on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61665/3954) to [Working with margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61448/3954)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\setlength\widest{0pt}%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\global\setlength\widest{\@tempdima}\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A medium label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first part, the width of the longest label is calculated: initially, `\widest` is set to `0pt`; for each `\item`, the length of its optional argument is measured and the length stored in `\@tempdima`; if `\@tempdima` is greater than `\widest`, (this is always true for the first `\item`) then `\widest` is updated to be `\@tempdima`. This is done for all `\item`s; `\BODY` is set inside a box that is never used. Then, a `description` environment is used, setting `\labelwidth` to the previously calculated value for `\widest`.

Answers to follow-up questions:

- **Q:** *What is the point of `\setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}`?*
  **A:** This just boxes `\BODY` without typesetting it.
- **Q:** *Since `\BODY` is used twice, what happens if `\BODY` contains something that has side effects (writes to the `.aux` file, contains `\newcommand`, contains `\footnote`, etc.)?*
  **A:** There's no problem with what `\BODY` contains (as long as it's reasonable for a standard description, so, for example, sectional unit commands won't be allowed, but they don't make sense in a description anyways).
- **Q:** *Why is that stuff wrapped in a `\vbox{}`?*
  **A:** The `\vbox` is used to prevent the dreadful "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." error at the beginning of a list (`\hbox` or `\mbox` could have also been used instead).

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain how this works?  I thought I would have to somehow save the widest length to the `.aux` file and reuse it in a second pass, but your example shows that this is not necessary.  I'm not sure how you do it without requiring a second pass.

Comment: @RichardHansen I added a short explanation at the end of my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating it, but I still have some questions:  Why is that stuff wrapped in a `\vbox{}`?  What is the point of `\setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}`?  Doesn't redefining `\item` affect spacing and `\label`?  Since `\BODY` is used twice, what happens if `\BODY` contains something that has side effects (writes to the `.aux` file, contains `\newcommand`, contains `\footnote`, etc.)?

Comment: @RichardHansen For some reason I didn't receive the notification of your last comment, so I just casually saw it. `\setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}` just boxes `\BODY` without typesetting it. There's no problem with what `\BODY` contains (as long as it's reasonable for a standerd `descrition`, so, for example, sectional unit commands won't be allowed, but they don't make sense in a `description` anyways). The `\vbox` is used to prevent the dreadful "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item`." error at the beginning of a list (`\hbox` or `\mbox` could have also been used instead).

Comment: @RichardHansen Just a Hint : It would be advisable to ask GonzaloMedina to add his explanation from comments to answer by pinging him so that he would make the answer flow continuous and smooth.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I was surprised to find that simply loading the `mathtools` package breaks your solution. I posted a question about this: [Why conflict between mathtools and Gonzalo's solution for auto-adjusting description environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461056/why-conflict-between-mathtools-and-gonzalos-solution-for-auto-adjusting-descrip)

Comment: Turns out that the conflict is more fundamental than with `mathtools`; the conflict is with `calc` (which is called by `mathtools`). `calc` redefines `\setlength`. Marmot replaced `\setlength` in the above code with `=` and it now works with `\calc`. See  [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461060/7922) to [Why conflict between mathtools and Gonzalo's solution for auto-adjusting description environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461056/why-conflict-between-mathtools-and-gonzalos-solution-for-auto-adjusting-descrip)