# Indented paragraph after word on same line

Tags: indentation

I want to do this:

```
Term        This is the definition of the word. No matter how much is typed
            here it should always line up like this. How do I do this? I am
            not sure since there is another word on the first line.

Next Term   Not to mention, the alignment should be consistent for multiple
            entries as well. The entries may span multiple pages as well.
```

I am using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Should items be breakable across the page boundary?

Comment: Ideally not mid-item, but there will definitely be enough entries to span multiple pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\widest

\begin{document}

red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 
red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 

\settowidth\widest{\textbf{word}}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+\labelsep\relax,labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
\item[word]
red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 
red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 
\item[that]
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For an automatic calculation of the widest label, you can see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/3954) to [Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130097/3954).

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


\begin{description}
\item[word]
red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 
red yellow blue, red yellow blue, red yellow blue, 
\item[that]
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
one two three four, one two three four, one two three four, 
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very close but not exactly what I need without some modification. The indentation is not precise. I will clarify my response.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just use a table, but depending on what you really want to put in the right column, this may be restrictive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX}
         Term & This is the definition of the word. No matter how much is typed here it should always line up like this. How do I do this? I am not sure since there is another word on the first line. \\
         Next Term & Not to mention, the alignment should be consistent for multiple
         entries as well. The entries may span multiple pages as well.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```