# The Environ package misbehaviour on empty content

Tags: environments, expansion

I have encountered a problem with the environ package.
It returns a wrong \BODY value when the content of an
environment is empty. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{env}[1]{\BODY}
\begin{document}
\begin{env}{abc}\end{env}
\end{document}
```

This code generates `\BODY=bc`. It can also be checked that `#1=a`. 
The results are wrong not only when the content is just empty but also
when it evaluates to an empty text,
for example when the content is commented out.

The version of the package I work with is 2014/05/04 v0.3.

Best regards,
Ryszard

Comment: Add some content for the body:  `\begin{env}{abc}
Some
\end{env}` However, you are not using `#1` at all.

Comment: @HarishKumar, this is obviously a test, `environ` shouldn't do this

Comment: I've pinged the author.

Comment: If `\end{env}` is on a line by itself or (equivalently) if `{abc}` and `\end{env}` are separated by a space, there is no problem.

Comment: the problem is `\def\collect@@body#1\end#2{%` which drops braces if `#1` is a brace group. You see also the wrong thing with `\begin{env}{abc}{xyz}\end{env}` it prints OK in that case but `\show\BODY` would show `xyz` not `{xyz}`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
 \def\collect@@body#1\end#2{%
```

which drops braces if `#1` is a brace group. You see also the wrong thing with

```
\begin{env}{abc}{xyz}\end{env}
```

it prints OK in that case but `\show\BODY` would show `xyz` not `{xyz}`

this is part way to a fix, it adds a `!` so the `#1` is never empty and then removes it later. It isn't complete as it still drops braces in the `{jjj}` case as seen from the  lof generated by the example below  which produces

```
[macro:->abc] [macro:->]
[macro:->abc] [macro:->jjj]
[macro:->abc] [macro:->{}abc]
```

But it does cover the case in the question as seen by the first line above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{env}[1]{%
  \def\arg{#1}\typeout{[\meaning\arg] [\meaning\BODY]}%
  \BODY}

\makeatletter
\long\def\Collect@Body#1{%
  \@envbody{\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\@envbody}}%
  \edef\process@envbody{\the\@envbody\noexpand\end{\@currenvir}}%
  \@envbody={}%
  \def\begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\let\csname\@currenvir\endcsname\Collect@@Body
  \edef\process@envbody{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname\@currenvir\endcsname!}%
  \process@envbody
}
\long\def\Collect@@Body#1\end#2{%
  \edef\begin@stack{%
    \expandafter\Push@Begins\@gobble#1\begin\end\expandafter\@gobble\begin@stack}%
  \ifx\@empty\begin@stack
    \endgroup
    \@checkend{#2}%
    \expandafter\Addto@Envbody\expandafter{\@gobble#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\Addto@Envbody\expandafter{\@gobble#1\end{#2}}%
  \fi
  \process@envbody}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{env}{abc}\end{env}


\begin{env}{abc}{jjj}\end{env}


\begin{env}{abc}{}abc\end{env}


\end{document}
```