# Set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label (with mathtools loaded)

Tags: description, mathtools

I would like to set the description's width automatically to the widest. The solution at [Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130097/automatically-set-description-list-labelwidth-based-on-widest-label)
works for me, *except* if I have the mathtools package loaded.

The following MWE, which is the same as Gonzalo's but loads the mathtools package, is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\setlength\widest{0pt}%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\global\setlength\widest{\@tempdima}\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A medium label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\end{document}
```

If I remove mathtools, it works. But I need mathtools.

Comment: It doesn't like applied maths: it claims everything is `0.0pt`.

Comment: This not related to `mathtools` directly, but `mathtools` load the `calc` package which changes how `\setlength` behave. This is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the cause of the problem, but for some reason when `mathtools` is loaded the change to `\widest` inside the `\vbox{...}` is only being made locally and it is not propagating globally (You can see this by adding some `\typeout{...}` commands in appropriate places). One fix to to use `\newdimen` rather than `newlength` to create `\widest`. With dimensions, rather than lengths, you get what you want.

Here is the modified working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}

\newdimen\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \global\widest=0pt%
  \vbox{%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A medium label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem just that `mathtools` loads `calc` in which case making `\setlength` global gets difficult.

Comment: @daleif Yes, I think you're right. The [calc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package is the problem and `calc` does change how these behave with `\global`.

Comment: @daleif Do you know why `calc` does that?

Comment: @cfr Ask the developers, I'm guessing it is the cost of the calculating feature. Might be mentioned in the calc manual