# Enumerate with two columns

Tags: enumerate

I'd like to have an enumerate with two columns. The first one report the name of the property and the second one can be a multiline text and it should be indented correctly. Thus second columns' text should follow the document's margin.

Something like this:
[image]

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] \textbf{Diagonal}, if all its elements outside the main diagonal are equal to zero, that is $\forall i\neq j$, $a_{ij} = 0 $ 
\item[] \textbf{Scalar}, if all off-diagonal elements are zero and all on-diagonal elements are equal 
\item[] \textbf{Identity}, if it's scalar and the elements on its main diagonal are all equal to 1, that is $\forall i$, $a_{ii} = 1$ 
\item[] \textbf{Lower triangular}, if all the entries above the main diagonal are zero, that is $\forall i > j$, $a_{ij} = 0$ 
\item[] \textbf{Upper triangular}, if all the entries below the main diagonal are zero, that is $\forall i < j$, $a_{ij} = 0$
\end{enumerate}
Below, a brief summary of the matrix operations used:
\begin{enumerate}
\item[] \textbf{Addition}: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same size then the sum $A$ and $B$ is defined by $C = A + B$, where 
\begin{equation}
c_{ij} = a_{ij}+b_{ij} \quad \forall i,j
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
```

Using leandriis' link, this is what I obtained
[image]

"Diagonal" has \quad\quad after it, and I would like to indent all the text in the second column
"Scalar" is the normal result.

Comment: Will the list be longer than a single page? If not, you could use a `table` for this.

Comment: it'd be, actually. It's a list of properties.

Comment: It sounds like you really want a `description` environment. If you use the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package it is straightforward to set the widest "report name".

Comment: Could you please clarify the desired output? Do you want a number, than the name and then the long text or dou you want your list no be unnumbered?

Comment: @leandriis updated.

Comment: Rather than a screenshot give us some code to work with...

Comment: @Andrew done...

Comment: @JackLametta: As Andrew already mentioned, you can use the `description` environment for this. In order to automatically calculate the width of the widest entry in the first "column", you could use the solution presented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/134144

Comment: @leandriis I'll update the request with what you linked.

Comment: When using a `description` environment, I don't think that @leandriis would recommend writing `\item[] \textbf{Diagonal}` (and likewise for the other list items). Instead, you should write `\item[Diagonal]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `longtable` environment may be well suited for your typesetting needs.

You may see fit to adjust the width of the second column depending on (a) the width of the first column and (b) the overall width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A matrix is said to be
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\bfseries}l P{0.6\textwidth} @{}}
Diagonal & if all its elements outside the main diagonal are equal to zero, that is $\forall i\neq j$, $a_{ij} = 0 $\\
Scalar & if all off-diagonal elements are zero and all on-diagonal elements are equal\\
Identity & if it is scalar and the elements on its main diagonal are all equal to 1, that is, $\forall i$, $a_{ii} = 1$ \\
Lower triangular & if all the entries above the main diagonal are zero, that is, $\forall i > j$, $a_{ij} = 0$ \\
Upper triangular & if all the entries below the main diagonal are zero, that is, $\forall i < j$, $a_{ij} = 0$
\end{longtable}

\bigskip\noindent
Below, a brief summary of the matrix operations used:
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\bfseries}l P{0.7\textwidth} @{}}
Addition & If $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same size then the sum of $A$ and $B$ is defined by $C = A + B$, where
\begin{equation}
c_{ij} = a_{ij}+b_{ij} \quad \forall i,j
\end{equation}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it! But the bold entries are not tabbed. Could you help me with it, please?

Comment: and is it possible to have the same space between the elements that it's present in the document between the rows?

Comment: @JackLametta - Please clarify what you mean by "the bold entries are not tabbed" and " the same space between the elements that it's present in the document between the rows". Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to have the same interspace that there is between rows of the document also between the element of the longtable.

Comment: @JackLametta - I'm afraid I don't follow you. If the row spacing in the `longtable` environment is different from that in the rest of your document, it must because you've made some changes to the default line spacing that you haven't told us about so far.

Comment: outside of the longtable all is fine. I would like to apply the same row spacing between the longtable's elements. @Mico

Comment: The crucial, still missing piece of information is what the line spacing *outside* the `longtable` environment is set to. E.g., is the main document set to single-, 1.5x-, or double-spacing? Without knowledge of this setting, it is not possible to know how to adjust the line spacing *inside* the `longtable` environment.

Comment: It's the default one, I guess is 1.5x

Comment: @JackLametta - Actually, single-spacing, not 1.5x-spacing, is the default line spacing. What matters, then, is *how* the default line-spacing was changed in the main document. You may not be aware of this, but you come across as quite unwilling to provide essential information. I find it quite impossible to provide helpful advice when essential information is withheld. I've gotten the impression in the meantime that my proposed solution is of no use to you. If this impression is correct, please withdraw the checkmark and I'll gladly delete the answer.