# Cannot remove label indentation with \alph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

The following MWE produces a little indentation before the label (a) of the items in the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}
    \noindent A line.

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*]
        \item A line.
    \end{enumerate}

    \noindent A line.

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
        \item A line.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(As you see, this does not happen using numbers.) How do I remove it?

Comment: It's [based on the width of m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzOJ.png) would you want the labelwidth to stay as is but the label be left aligned (so having a bigger gap after thin letters) or do you want variable lable width?

Comment: Ah, good point. Is there a way to automatically use the "lowest gap necessary"? (So almost the same if my list goes, say, from (a) to (e).) I guess this is what you mean with variable table.

Comment: That would require two runs to record the length of the list, as it is the list label is set up before the list starts

Comment: I see! It seems something like that has already been answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130097/automatically-set-description-list-labelwidth-based-on-widest-label