# Enumitem based environment for automatic calculation of labelwidth in descriptions can not be nested

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, margins, indentation, enumitem

In [Working with margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61448/working-with-margins/61665#61665) [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) proposed the below environment for gathering the maximal width of a `description`-label. Unfortunately this code only works as long as the environment `xdesc` is not nested. In case of nesting (see below) the code will return

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Here is a nestified version of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newlength{\xdescwd}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{xdesc}{%
  \vbox{\hbadness=\@M \global\xdescwd=0pt
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}:}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\xdescwd \global\xdescwd=\@tempdima\fi}
  \BODY}
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
    labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=left]\BODY\end{description}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

En un contexto determinado, las palabras poseen, además de su
significado literal, también una dimensión intencional. Un texto es la
manifestación lingüística de la intención del emisor dirigida a un
receptor. Si consideramos, pues, los actos ilocutivos implicados, un
texto cumplirá funciones diferentes.

La función textual es el efecto de los textos en una situación
comunicativa según los objetivos que queremos alcanzar. Un texto puede
desempeñar las siguientes funciones:

\begin{xdesc}
\item[Representativa:] llamada también asertiva, cuando se afirma o se 
    \begin{xdesc}
    \item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                      considera verdadero.
    \end{xdesc}     
\item[Informativa:] cuando se presenta algo de manera neutra, sin
     énfasis que pueda denotar emotividad, como por ejemplo un titular
     de una noticia.
\item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. En la legislación, por
     ejemplo, se emplean formas modales deónticas (deber + infinitivo)
\item[Persuasiva:] cuando se trata de convencer al interlocutor
\item[Comisiva:] cuando se promete, jura, ofrece, etc.
\item[Fática:] cuando el emisor se centra en el interlocutor y procura
               mantener el contacto con él, como por ejemplo “Oye…”
\item[Expresiva:] cuando el emisor se alegra, agradece, felicita.
\end{xdesc}

\end{document}
```

Beyond that even the original code produces a strange duplication of the text of the items above the `xdesc`-environment.

[image: egreg's two-pass code compiled with pdflatex]

Since I really would like to implement the idea of egreg's code in an environment of my own any kind of help would be appreciated.

### [Update 2016/12/04] Here is an addition to my original question concerning the answers of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) and [Andrew](https://web.archive.org/web/20200918221904/https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30471/andrew) below:

Unfortunately after further testing in the wild the following problem came up: egreg's `xdesc` breaks compatibility with the normal `enumerate`-environment. Within the normal environment it is possible to have \items without any text. But in `xdesc` a textless item disappears. (The same is true of Andrew's code.) I tried some modifications without success. So I have no clue how to prevent `xdesc` from eating up textless items. Since I need the functionality of enumerate, any help would be welcome. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\xdescwd}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter%
\NewEnviron{xdesc}{% I only changed "description" to "enumerate"
               % and did some formatting
              \setbox0=\vbox{%
                             \hbadness=\@M \global\xdescwd=0pt
                             \RenewEnviron{xdesc}{}%
                             \def\item[##1]{%
                             \settowidth\@tempdima{##1}%
                             \ifdim\@tempdima>\xdescwd \global\xdescwd=\@tempdima\fi}
                             \BODY%
                             }%
               \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
                                labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
                                labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=left]
               \BODY%
               \end{enumerate}%
               }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
Here is what \textbf{enumerate} does:

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(DF)] %llamada también asertiva, cuando se afirma o se

        \begin{enumerate}
        \item[(1)] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                    considera verdadero.
        \item[(1a)] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                    considera verdadero.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Here is what \textbf{xdesc} does:

\begin{xdesc}
\item[(DF)] %llamada también asertiva, cuando se afirma o se

        \begin{xdesc}
        \item[(1)] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                    considera verdadero.
        \item[(1a)] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                    considera verdadero.
        \end{xdesc}
\end{xdesc}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: output of enumerate and xdesc]

**[End of Update 2016/12/04]**

Comment: Please, when you ask a question, it should be complete. It's *obvious* that you cannot nest an `enumerate` environment in `xdesc`.

Comment: @egreg I did not nest `enumerate` in `xdesc`, but `xdesc` in `xdesc`. The enumerate-example is only meant as a contrast case to make the difference obvious. (Thanks for the hint to open up a new question in case of need for further clarification.)

Comment: I do not understand why it works, but putting the first token of `\BODY` in a `hbox` prevents the code from eating up items without text. Hopefully this doesn't have unwanted side-effects...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\xdescwd}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{xdesc}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\hbadness=\@M \global\xdescwd=0pt
    \RenewEnviron{xdesc}{}%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}:}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\xdescwd \global\xdescwd=\@tempdima\fi}
  \BODY}
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
    labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=left]\BODY\end{description}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

En un contexto determinado, las palabras poseen, además de su
significado literal, también una dimensión intencional. Un texto es la
manifestación lingüística de la intención del emisor dirigida a un
receptor. Si consideramos, pues, los actos ilocutivos implicados, un
texto cumplirá funciones diferentes.

La función textual es el efecto de los textos en una situación
comunicativa según los objetivos que queremos alcanzar. Un texto puede
desempeñar las siguientes funciones:

\begin{xdesc}
\item[Representativa:] llamada también asertiva, cuando se afirma o se 
    \begin{xdesc}
    \item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                      considera verdadero.
    \item[Prescriptivaaaa:] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                      considera verdadero.
    \end{xdesc}    
\item[Informativa:] cuando se presenta algo de manera neutra, sin
     énfasis que pueda denotar emotividad, como por ejemplo un titular
     de una noticia.
\item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. En la legislación, por
     ejemplo, se emplean formas modales deónticas (deber + infinitivo)
\item[Persuasiva:] cuando se trata de convencer al interlocutor
\item[Comisiva:] cuando se promete, jura, ofrece, etc.
\item[Fática:] cuando el emisor se centra en el interlocutor y procura
               mantener el contacto con él, como por ejemplo “Oye…”
\item[Expresiva:] cuando el emisor se alegra, agradece, felicita.
\end{xdesc}

\end{document}
```

When the `\vbox` is being set for measuring, `xdesc` is redefined to do nothing.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you very much! I specifically cherish the compactness of the code. Compared to [Andrew](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30471/andrew)'s code above your code adjusts the labelwidth for each **token** of a xdesk-_environment_, what is exactly what I need.

Comment: Please see my follow-up question in the original question above.

Answer (score 3):

There are really two problems here. First, you need to fix the missing item error and, secondly, I think that you want the maximum label widths for each level of nesting to be different so you need to keep track of the nesting level.

The missing item error I fix by setting `\item\setitemwidth` the first time `\BODY` is used and then resetting it to the original `\item` command directly afterwards.

For the nesting issue, the description environment uses `\@listdepth` to keep track of this but we cannot use this because we compute the widest labels before we enter the `description` environment, so I have added a counter `xdescdepth` to keep track of this. I then store the label widths in `widest<xdescepth>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\newdimen\widest
\newcounter{xdescdepth}
\makeatletter
\def\setitemwidth[#1]{% compute maximum width of labels for nesting depth
    \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{#1}}%
    \ifdim\@tempdima>\csuse{widest\thexdescdepth}%
       \csdimgdef{widest\thexdescdepth}{\@tempdima}%
    \fi%
}
\let\realitem\item% save the real \item command
\NewEnviron{xdesc}{%
  \addtocounter{xdescdepth}{1}% increment nesting depth
  % initialise label width to 0pt at the start of each nesting level
  \ifcsdef{widest\thexdescdepth}{\relax}%
          {\csdef{widest\thexdescdepth}{0pt}}%
  \let\item\setitemwidth% temporarily override \item
  \setbox0=\vbox{\BODY}% compute label widths without printing anything
  \let\item\realitem% reset \item
  \widest=\dimexpr\csuse{widest\thexdescdepth}\relax%
  \description[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest
    ]
    \BODY
  \enddescription%
  \addtocounter{xdescdepth}{-1}% decrement nesting depth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{xdesc}
  \item[Representativa:] llamada también asertiva, cuando se afirma o se
      \begin{xdesc}
      \item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                        considera verdadero.
      \end{xdesc}
  \item[Informativa:] cuando se presenta algo de manera neutra, sin
       énfasis que pueda denotar emotividad, como por ejemplo un titular
       de una noticia.
  \item[Prescriptiva:] cuando se establecen normas. En la legislación, por
       ejemplo, se emplean formas modales deónticas (deber + infinitivo)
  \item[Persuasiva:] cuando se trata de convencer al interlocutor
  \item[Comisiva:] cuando se promete, jura, ofrece, etc.
      \begin{xdesc}
      \item[Prescrip] cuando se establecen normas. anuncia algo que se
                        considera verdadero.
      \end{xdesc}
  \item[Fática:] cuando el emisor se centra en el interlocutor y procura
                 mantener el contacto con él, como por ejemplo “Oye…”
  \item[Expresiva:] cuando el emisor se alegra, agradece, felicita.
  \end{xdesc}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only for the code but for the great explanation. Compared to [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s code below your macro adjusts the labelwidth of the itemlabels for **all list tokens of the same level**. Since this allows a quite consistent layout of a complex list I see this as a feature!