# Alignment and width with tcolorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox, boxes

I'm writing a document where I need to put some text inside a box. I have figured out how to make a rounded-corner box with the graphical appearence I was looking for.

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{enhanced,
  colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!7!white,
  boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt, hbox}


\begin{document}

\mybox{\textbf{Assumption 1:} Atmospheric forces can be neglected.}

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image]

I would like to know how:

1. Indent the box when it is located at the beginning of a section or paragraph. I've tried `\indent` but it seems to not work.
2. How to control the width of the box. When I write a long text it exceeds the page margins. I would like to set the width to constrain the box size and force the text to fit inside the width I have choosen (just in case of a long text).
3. When a long text wraps to start a new line within the box, I would like to get an alignment just after the colon, i.e. ":", and not with the first world of the box as normally happens.
4. It is more a curiosity: I've defined a `\tcbset{enhanced,colframe={violet!60},colback={black!3!white}, drop shadow}` for another box inside the document. Why my "assumption box" acquires the drop shadow option and displays it?

Here some examples of the result I would like to get:

[image]

I would appreciate a lot any kind of help. However, It would be great If someone could provide me a MWE to accomplish the whole task.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the shown box. In fact your code is missing `[most]` option which allows `enhanced` option. And as you don't use `drop shadow` in `mybox` option, it doesn't add any drop shadow to resulting box.

Comment: I'm sorry @Ignasi, I've forgotten to add `[most]` on the original MWE I have written. It is actually present in my current code. I don't still get the point.

Comment: My point 4 lecture was wrong. `\tcbset` fixes options for all boxes, therefore `drop shadow` inside `tcbset` will apply this shadow to all boxes unless you use `no shadow`. It's better that you use `\tcbset{ style-name/.style={...}}` to define several styles and apply them  to particular tcolorboxes.

Comment: I've solved the point 4 in this way: I have left `\newtcbox` to define my "assumption box", called `\mybox` as the MWE shows. The other box, that was defined by `\tcbset`, now it has been defined by `\tcboxmath[option]{formula}`, given that it contains a math equation. However, I keep needing help with points 1,2 and 3. I hope that someone come forward.

Comment: Update: It seems I've solved point 1. I've found the option `left skip=length` inside `tcolorbox` package, where I replaced "lenght" with my current indentation parameter, equal to 15pt. I don't know if it is a proper way to do it, but it works. Any further suggestions are welcome though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcolorbox` offers two kind of boxes `tcbox` and `tcolorbox`. First ones are for a short texts which won't break in lines while seconds can contain longer texts and use a whole line as default width. Therefore, I think that what OP wants is not possible with a unique command.

Following code proposes an environment (tcolorbox) for the larger boxes. The inner contents described by OP looks like a `description` environment. I've assumed that the box only contains one `item`. The alignment has been taken from an [egreg`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61665/1952)

`longbox` environment has one optional and one mandatory parameters. The mandatory is the item title while the optional will be applied as `tcolorbox` options to change box format (even width).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newlength{\xdescwd}
\newenvironment{xdesc}[1]
  {\settowidth{\xdescwd}{\textbf{#1:}}%
   \begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\xdescwd+.5em\relax,
     labelindent=0pt,labelsep=.5em,
     labelwidth=\xdescwd,align=right]\item[#1:]}
  {\end{description}}

\newtcolorbox{longbox}[2][]{before upper={\begin{xdesc}{#2}},after upper={\end{xdesc}}, 
    enhanced, breakable, colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!7!white,
    boxrule=0.5pt, arc=4pt, boxsep=0pt, left=6pt, right=6pt, top=5pt, bottom=5pt, #1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longbox}[width=.8\linewidth]{Assumption 1}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{longbox}

\begin{longbox}[colback=red!30, sharp corners]{Example}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{longbox}

\begin{longbox}{Example}
Only one line
\end{longbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Ignasi for the amazing effort. That's the kind of code I needed. I have added `left skip=length` inside your suggested code, just to set the indentation I need. For the shortest boxes I will keep using `tcbox`, so that the box adapts to the shorter text with the `hbox` option.