# customize space between lines and space to the left in enumeration

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I would like to modify the enumeration in such a way that:

1. there is no margin on the left (in the default enumeration, the numbering is indented from the left)
2. there is a vertical space between two items.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Not sure what you mean by "there is no margin on the left" and "numbering is indented from the left".  These two seem to conflicting requirements. Perhaps you should post an image of what is desired.  Best place to start to look would be documentation for [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem).

Comment: I _don't_ want indentation from the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all of your list spacing needs, you should use the `enumitem` package.  For no indentation, and a blank line between items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is some text.
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,itemsep=\baselineskip]
\item Foo
\item Bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For some other questions involving list spacing see:

- [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/2693)
- [Indentation in list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35594/2693)

Comment: I mean a vertical space, not a horizontal space. So I want an empty line between two items of the list.

Comment: @MichaelWidyuan See my edit.  (And read the documentation for `enumitem` for more information.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry to ask so much, but is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: @MichaelWidyuan Surely you can figure this out from either the documentation or the first linked question.  Hint: apply the stuff in the `[ ... ]` from this answer to the examples in that question.